# Using Javascript inside a dynamically load UserControl in jQuery Ui Tabs

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, user-controls, jquery-ui-tabs

I need to insert some JavaScript code inside a UserControl that I load from an Ajax call via jQuery Ui Tabs. Let me explain...

This is my View (with jQuery loaded)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#tabs").tabs({
        cache: false,
        });
        getContentTab (1);
    });

    function getContentTab(index) {
        var url='<%= Url.Content("~/Home/getUserControl") %>/' + index;
        var targetDiv = "#tabs-" + index;

        $.get(url,null, function(result) {
            $(targetDiv).html(result);
        });
    }
</script>

<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1" onclick="getContentTab(1);">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2" onclick="getContentTab(2);">Proin dolor</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3" onclick="getContentTab(3);">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
    </div>
</div>
```

With these lines of code I call the Ajax function to load the content into a DIV. 
This is the Action from the controller:

```
public ActionResult getUserControl(int num)
    {
        return PartialView("TestUC", num);
    }
```

And this is the UserControl...

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl" %>
Number... <span id="testSpan"><%=Model.ToString() %></span>!! 
<input type="button" value="Click me!!" onclick="message();" />
<script type="text/javascript">
function message(item) {
    alert($("#testSpan").html());
}
</script>
```

The problem is that the message() function returns always 1 (instead of returning the correct number).

My question is... How should I add the script to my UserControl in order to have my code running correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I'm just guessing here.

I guess your problem is that when a tab is loaded, it stays in the DOM even if you open another one (i.e. If the #1 is the default, it will remain loaded even if you click on the second one).

If this is happening, when you call the message function, there will be multiple elements with the id "testSpan", and the jQuery selector $("#testSpan") will return the first of them.

I suppose this is just some test code, but for this particular case I would go with adding the <%= Model.ToString() %> as an argument to the javascript function.

Again, I'm just guessing about the behavior of the jquery-ui tabs() function.

Regards

Comment: This could be a solution, but I solved in a different (more clean IMHO) way. 
Now, I empty the content of the previous tab, in that way the ID are always unique. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try Adding script like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" defer="defer">
function message(item) {
    alert($("#testSpan").html());
}
</script>
```